# Import Modal from another JS file throws error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import { 
      getPasswordsByUserID, 
      createPassword, 
      deletePassword, 
      updatePassword 
    } from "../models";
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import Passwords from '../components/Passwords';
    import NavbarComponent from '../components/Navbar';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
    import { Flash } from '../components/Flash/flash';
    
    const AppDashboard = () => {
      const history = useHistory()
      if (!localStorage.getItem('email')) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.flash('You need to be logged in', 'warning')
        }, 100)
        history.push('/login')
      }
    
      const [passwords, setPasswords] = useState([])
      const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false)
    
      const handleCreate = async password => {
      // save to dB
        password.userId = localStorage.getItem('email')
        const newPassword = await createPassword(
          password.accountName, 
          password.accountUrl,
          password.email,
          password.encryptedPassword,
          password.userId
        )
        setPasswords([newPassword, ...passwords])
        window.flash('New contact created successfully', 'success')
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setIsPending(true)
        const getContacts = async () => {
          let passwordData = await getPasswordsByUserID(localStorage.getItem('email'))
          setPasswords(passwordData)
        }
        getContacts()
        setIsPending(false)
      }, [])
    
     return (
     <>
      <NavbarComponent passwords={ passwords} handleCreate={ handleCreate }/>
      <Flash />
      <Passwords isPending={isPending} passwords={passwords}
          handleEdit={async payload => {
            await updatePassword({
              accountName: payload.accountName,
              accountUrl: payload.accountUrl,
              email: payload.email,
              encryptedPassword: payload.password
            }, payload.id)
            setPasswords(passwords.map( password => password.id === payload.id? payload : password))
          }}
          handleDelete={async id => {
            await deletePassword(id)
            setPasswords(passwords.filter( ele => ele.id !== id)) 
          }} 
      /> 
     </>
     );
    }
    
    export default AppDashboard;
```

This is App.js which call Navbar component.

```
    import {useState} from 'react'
    import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
    import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
    import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import CreatePasswordModal from '../components/createPassword.modal'
    import favicon from '../assets/favicon.png'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
    import { faUserCircle, faCog } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    
    const NavbarComponent = (props) => {
      const [createModalShow, setCreateModalShow] = useState(false);
      const handleHide = (url, password, email, name) => {
        let n = true
        if (url || password || email || name) {n = window.confirm("Your changes won't be saved...")}
        if (n) setCreateModalShow(false)
      }
    
      const handleCreate = payload => {
        props.handleCreate(payload)
        setCreateModalShow(false)
      }
    
     return (
      <Navbar expand="lg" className="navbar-fixed-top" 
      style={{position : "sticky", top : "0", zIndex: "10000", backgroundColor : "#d1e1f0e7"}}>
        <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/" style={{cursor : 'pointer'}}>
        <img src={favicon} alt="" style={{width : '40px', height : '40px'}} className="mr-2" /> 
        Password Manager
        </Navbar.Brand>
    
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="mt-2" style={{textDecoration : "none"}}>Home</Link>
    
            {!localStorage.getItem('email') ? 
              <>
                <NavDropdown title={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle} size="2x" className="text-primary" />} alignRight id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/login" className="text-primary">Sign in</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/register" className="text-primary">Register</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </>: 
              <>
                <NavDropdown title={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} size="2x" className="text-primary" />} alignRight id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/dashboard" className="text-primary" >Dashboard</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <CreatePasswordModal show={createModalShow} onHide={handleHide} handleCreate={ handleCreate } />
                  <NavDropdown.Item to="#" onClick={() => setCreateModalShow(true)} className="text-primary" >Create New Password</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Divider />
                  <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/logout" className="text-primary" >Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </>
            }
          </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      )
    }
    
    export default NavbarComponent
```

This is the Navbar component I am using.

```
    import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
    import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
    import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
    import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
    import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
    import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
    import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    import { useState } from 'react'
    import dotenv from 'dotenv'
    
    dotenv.config()
    
    const CreatePasswordModal = props => {
     const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState('')
     const [accountUrl, setAccountUrl] = useState('') 
     const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
     const [password, setPassword] = useState('') 
    
     const handleCreate = async () => {
      const payload = {
        accountName, 
        accountUrl,
        email,
        password
      }
      props.handleCreate(payload)
      setAccountName('')
      setAccountUrl('')
      setEmail('')
      setPassword('')
      window.flash('Password created successfully', 'success')
     }
    
      const onHide = () => {
        props.onHide(accountUrl, password, email, accountName)
      }
    
     return (
      <Modal
        {...props} size="xlg"  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered onHide={onHide}
      >
        <Modal.Header style={{backgroundColor : "#d1e1f0"}} closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Create New Password</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body className="show-grid">
          <Container>
            <Form>
              <Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                  <Form.Control placeholder="Account Name" value={accountName} onChange={(e) => setAccountName(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                  <Form.Control placeholder="Account URL" defaultValue={`https://${accountUrl}`} onChange={(e) => setAccountUrl(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                  <Form.Control type="email" value={email} placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                  <Form.Control type="password" value={password} placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </Container>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="success" onClick={handleCreate} disabled={(!accountUrl || !accountName || !email) ? true : false}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} size="1x" className="" />
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
     );
    }
    
    export default CreatePasswordModal
```

This is the createPassword Modal I am using.

In the lines

```
    const handleCreate = payload => {
        props.handleCreate(payload)
        setCreateModalShow(false)
      }
```

from Navbar component I am facing an error. It said **props.handleCreate is not a function, and React does not recognize the handleCreate prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase handlecreate instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

Can you please help me solve the error.

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? What is rendering `NavbarComponent` and possibly ***not*** passing a `handleCreate` function as a prop?

Comment: Yes will update it.

Comment: I have updated it, can you please check it now.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, wow... from what I can see it looks like `handleCreate` is defined in each component and passed down as a prop. Nothing obvious is jumping out. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese I am new to StackOverflow and not sure how to create _running codesandbox_ in Stackoverflow.

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is like an online web version of Vscode. Try copy/pasting in the code you've shared, or import from github if this project is a githhub repo,  and remove the extras down to a minimal example that hopefully reproduces the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241444/discussion-between-theghoul27-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @DrewReese https://dev.to/bkoiki950/building-a-password-manager-with-react-js-crypto-js-and-fauna-29g9
Here's the link to which I am referring infact I am running the same code to check how it works. I am referring the same.

Comment: Copy/pasted the above code snippets into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/import-modal-from-another-js-file-throws-error-in-reactjs-7yeqy?file=/src/App.js) and I don't see any issue with the `handleCreate` functions. Feel free to fork the sandbox and add in more of your code to see where it breaks. This will give you an idea what to do to fix your actual code.

Comment: @DrewReese did you check out this sample website https://dev.to/bkoiki950/building-a-password-manager-with-react-js-crypto-js-and-fauna-29g9 Here is the working example of it and it does create the same issue there also.

Comment: That appears to be a link to the tutorial (*or whatever*) that you are working from. Where's a working example that reproduces the issue you have?

Comment: @DrewReese here is the link to it. https://babatunde-password-manager.netlify.app/

Comment: I did check your codesandbox link. I see that you have added all the codes in the same App.js file. It works in the same file, but why does it not work in separate files?

Comment: Here's a [CSB fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/import-modal-from-another-js-file-throws-error-in-reactjs-forked-s9r1x?file=/src/App.js) with the components split out into their own files, it still seems to function without issue. Can you create a *running* codesandbox of your code, or provide reproduction steps for your live website?

Comment: @DrewReese I am not able to recreate the same error on the codesandbox, I have mailed you with some details. If possible do check it and let me know.

Comment: @DrewReese here's the link to the complete project by the **Original Author: Babatunde. I am just trying to recreate the same.** https://github.com/Babatunde13/password-manager
This is the link to it. Please do refer to this and help me out with the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese here is the _codesandbox_ link for the same project. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-paper-38ssv
Please do refer to it once.

Comment: In that sandbox I still had to invert the ternary condition in `Navbar` to get into the branch with the modal, and it renders without issue. Is this your code or that of the other github project? Do you have your code hosted in a public github?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/TheGhoul27/password-manager-react.git, here's the link to it.

Comment: Is your repo just a fork of the other project's repo? It seems to also have no issue rendering the `CreatePasswordModal` modal.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to figure out the issue where in line props.handleCreate in NavBar.js. It says it isn't a function.

Comment: https://github.com/TheGhoul27/password-manager-react/blob/master/src/assets/error.png here is to the image link I am facing the issue.

Comment: Oh, right..... sorry, I forgot what the issue was you were chasing. What are the steps to reproduce the issue then? Again, sorry for my confusion.

Comment: First off, once you pull the full repo now, you need to install the necessary python packages from requirements.txt, then run the app.py. Once this is done you need to run the react app and register some dummy account, there is nothing to worry as it'll be stored in the local machine. Once this is done in the navbar you try adding a dummy password, it doesn't do it.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now. All the screen components are rendering a `NavbarComponent` component, but not all of them are passing props. This is why `handleCreate` is undefined in the `Home` component rendered on `"/"`.

Comment: Yes, this is where I am stuck. It renders but the issue persists. Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: You need to provide all the props the `NavbarComponent` component needs, in all the places `NavbarComponent` is rendered. Do you need so many `NavbarComponent` components? Usually an app renders just one in the root `App` component.

Comment: I am not sure how to provide all props. Yes, I do need the `NavBarComponent` as it calls it every time, I finish a work. Is there any other way I can just call it once and make it work the same way I want it to work? - @DrewReese

Comment: If you look in `NavbarComponent` it seems the only prop it *actually* consumes is the `handleCreate` callback. You need to provide a `handleCreate` callback as a prop to each `NavbarComponent`.

Comment: Can you provide a small instruction on how to do it?

Comment: You only need to provide a defined callback as a prop, something like `<NavbarComponent handleCreate={handleCreate} />`, and so long as you define `handleCreate` in the component rendering the navbar it should work. You could probably even copy/paste the code from the app dashboard component into the others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241605/discussion-between-theghoul27-and-drew-reese).